# How to work on IsDisplayed() in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, display, assertion

Here I have Created page factory for both buttons

```java
    @FindBy (id = "book-seat")
    WebElement SlotBooking;
    
    @FindBy (id = "proceed-to-purchase")
    WebElement SlotBookingConfirmation;
```

1. Hi Have two buttons in UI. For the first time Book Slot Button will display and next It will ask for Book SLot Confirmation Button.
2. If i run the same test case again Book Slot button not showing. It is showing Slot Confirmation button
3. Is there any way to validate if element is displayed() select SlotBooking button or else select SlotBookingConfirmation button

Comment: Please add more context to the question like give code snippet of whole class. It will help others to answer or try it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Try with an if statement:

```
if (SlotBooking.isDisplayed()){
     SlotBooking.click;
}
SlotBookingConfirmation.click;
```

Comment: Hi Tamas, Tried above step. getting no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: Is the exception pointing towards id = "book-seat"? Maybe use isVisible() instead of isDisplayed()
But you might have to put the locator inside the if, instead of @FindBy, there are cases where this is not working as we would expect